# RTSP on Django using OpenCV

Tags: python, django, opencv

I need to stream a surveillance camera onto a Django based website. I found a tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wI6tzRogZQ) but it is very simple. Down below is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators import gzip
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

import cv2

# Create your views here.

@gzip.gzip_page
def Home(request):
    try:
        cam = videoCamera()
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(cam), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
    except:
        pass

    return render(request, 'index.html')


# Video Capture
class videoCamera(object):

    video = cv2.VideoCapture("[user]:[password]@rtsp://[ip-address]:554/sub")

    while True:
        _, frame = video.read()
        cv2.imshow("RTSP", frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k == ord('q'):
            break

    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I encounter an error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
# views.py
def gen_frames(stream_url, stream_id):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)
    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    frame = buffer.tobytes()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    streams = Stream.objects.all()

    context = {
        'streams': streams,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

@csrf_exempt
def video_feed(request, stream_id):
    stream = get_stream(stream_id)
    if stream.name == 'xyz':
        stream_url = f"rtsp://{username}:{password}@{ip_address}:554"

#models.py

class Stream(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    stream_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stream_name

# html

<body style="background-color: black">
    <h1 style="color: crimson">Cameras</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'add_stream' %}">Add Camera</a>
 
    <div class="row mb-3 text-center">
    {% for camera in cameras %}
        <h2 style="color: crimson">{{ stream.stream_name }}</h2>
        <div class="col-6 themed-grid-col">.col-6</div>
        <img src="{% url 'video_feed' stream.id %}" width="640" height="480" />
        <div class="col-6 themed-grid-col">.col-6</div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>

# urls

    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('video_feed/<int:stream_id>/', views.video_feed, name='video_feed'),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this in class videoCamera dont forget to import threading

```
class VideoCamera(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.video = cv2.VideoCapture("put your video link here")
       (self.grabbed , self.frame) = self.video.read()
       threading.Thread(target=self.update , args=()).start()
    
    
   def __del__(self):
       self.video.release()

   def get_frame(self):
       image = self.frame 
       _ , jpeg = cv2.imencode(' .jpg' , image)
       return jpeg.tobytes()

   def update(self):
       while True:
           (self.grabbed , self.frame) = self.video.read()
```